# Cannot receive String into Spring end point

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I use this code to receive values from POSTMAN as key-value:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> keyValuePairs) {

    LOGGER.debug("handleFormMessage");
    LOGGER.debug("keyValuePairs: {}", keyValuePairs);

    String unique_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("uniqueid"));
    String status = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("status"));
    String external_id = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("external_id"));
    String gateway = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("gateway"));
    String transaction_type = String.valueOf(keyValuePairs.get("transaction_type"));

    try {

      System.out.println("!!!!!");
      System.out.println("!!!! unique_id " + unique_id);

          System.out.println("!!!!! Entered if(paymentTransaction.isPresent()) {");

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Please contact technical support!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

I send these values from POSTMAN:

```
type=sale&
uniqueid=28357oxojqmehujo8auz9v27p0zrh1nl&
transaction_type=sale3d&
status=approved&
external_id=43435&
amount=500&
gateway=ipg&
signature=088e16a1019277b15d58faf0541e11910eb756f6&
```

I get this in log:

```
00:56:25,691 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 00:56:25.691 [default task-1] DEBUG o.d.r.a.s.controller.HomeController - handleFormMessage
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 00:56:25.692 [default task-1] DEBUG o.d.r.a.s.controller.HomeController - keyValuePairs: {
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) status=[approved], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) external_id=[43435], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) signature=[088e16a1019277b15d58faf0541e11910eb756f6], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) uniqueid=[28357oxojqmehujo8auz9v27p0zrh1nl], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) amount=[500], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) =[], type=[sale], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) gateway=[ipg], 
00:56:25,692 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) transaction_type=[sale3d]}
00:56:25,693 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) !!!!!
00:56:25,696 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) !!!! unique_id null
```

As you can se the values are received but the String unique_id is empty. Do you know why the values are null?

Application configuration:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter);
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
                ((XmlMapper) createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml()))
                        .enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION)));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json())));
    }
    .....
}
```

POSTMAN configuration:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you try in the following format since all the key values are of type String ? `"key1"="value1"&"key2"="value2"`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It prints the value correctly for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added the POSTMAN configuration.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I would suggest you to use a DTO class instead of `MultiValueMap`. and remove `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,` from your post mapping and send data in JSON . checkout this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Answer (score -1):

A `MultiValueMap` allows for multiple values for each key, which means each key refers to a `List<Object>`. Try changing the RequestBody type to `Map<String, String>`, unless your business case must support multiple values. Then your code simplifies to:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(@RequestBody Map<String, String> keyValuePairs) {
    String unique_id = keyValuePairs.get("uniqueid");
    String status = keyValuePairs.get("status");
    String external_id = keyValuePairs.get("external_id");
    String gateway = keyValuePairs.get("gateway");
    String transaction_type = keyValuePairs.get("transaction_type");
    ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The point of using `MultiValueMap` is so Spring MVC can use `FormHttpMessageConverter` to deserialize the POST body, which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Since form parameters can have multiple values, it has to be a multi map. Spring MVC (by default) does not know how to deserialize that type of content into a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is correct. I would recommend creating a specific class for the POST's body and posting with 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', but if the business case must support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then try the `MultiValueMap.getFirst()` method.